# Neo4j.rb 2.0 and devise 2.0. Is there any way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, jruby, neo4j

I want to use Neo4j database and JRuby on Rails to build a new web project. (I really need Neo4j or other graph database for this)

I am using neo4j 2.0 gem and trying to make authentication with Devise and Omniauth. Is there any way this combination will work?

I tried devise-neo4j but it is not compatible with neo4j.rb 2.0. I know that the last commit [here](https://github.com/andreasronge/devise-neo4j) says it is for neo4j.rb 2.0 but

```
gem 'neo4j'
gem 'devise-neo4j'
```

gives the following error when bundling:

```
  Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "neo4j":
  In Gemfile:
    devise-neo4j (>= 1.0.2) java depends on
      neo4j (~> 1.1.1) java

    neo4j (2.0.0.rc2)
```

I also tried the normal devise gem with neo4j:

```
gem 'neo4j'
gem 'devise'
```

but when I run `rails g devise:install` I get `NameError: uninitialized constant User`.

I searched and tried this a lot but couldn't get it working.

Does anyone know a good solution to this?
Or what is the *right* way to get this functionality (login with email/password and facebook,google,yahoo and twitter)? *Oh, I know I can code it myself, but I would really like to use something already done.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My devise-neo4j fork is not released to rubygems.org, which means you have to specify it in the Gemfile file as:

```
gem 'devise', '1.5.3'
gem 'devise-neo4j', :git => 'git://github.com/andreasronge/devise-neo4j.git'
```

Notice that devise-neo4j does currently not work with devise 2.0.

Comment: This appears to work with devise 3.0 and neo4j gem 2.3. At least it installs with bundler without conflict. Remember to add the github url.

Comment: I could not get this one to work, but I found another devise-neo4j that I could get to work: `gem 'devise-neo4j', :git => 'git://github.com/cfitz/devise-neo4j.git', :branch => 'devise2'`. I am running `neo4j 2.2.4` and `devise 2.2.7`.